# Are large cardinals bi-interperable with type theory?

Tags: reference-request, large-cardinals, type-theory

["Sets in Types, Types in Sets"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.1709) establishes that the calculus of constructions is bi-interpretable with ZFC + infinitely many inaccessibles.

Are there any more results like this higher up the large cardinal hierarchy?   What would a type theory capable of expressing stronger large cardinal properties look like? (without just jamming them in as axioms via Sets in Types)

Comment: Note that the paper by Werner you cite concerns the calculus of *inductive* constructions, not the mere calculus of constructions.  The latter is probably bi-interpretable with *Zermelo* set theory with infinitely many inaccessible or something similar.  So already the word "inductive" is a kind of large cardinal axiom for the calculus of constructions!